# Level sets and Manifolds

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, vector-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

Suppose $f \in C^1 (\mathbb{R}^{N+1},\mathbb{R})$. It's well known that if all his points are regular points i.e.
$$\nabla f (x) \neq 0 \; \; \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{N+1}$$
then, for every fixed $c \in \mathbb{R}$, the level set:
$$f^{-1}(c)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{N+1}: f(x)=c\}$$
is a $C^1$ manifold of dimension $N$.

Now suppose that not all his points are regular and let $Crit(f)$ be the set of critical points of $f$ i.e.
$$Crit(f):=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{N+1}: \nabla f (x)=0 \}$$
Suppose that, with a  variant of Sard theorem, we can prove that:
$$H_N \left( f^{-1}(c) \cap Crit(f) \right)=0 \; \; \; for \;a.e. \; c \in \mathbb{R}$$
where $H_N$ is the $N$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

The question is: can I say that $f^{-1}(c)$ is a $C^1$ manifold of dimension $N$ for $a.e. \; c \in \mathbb{R}$?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure about your "Suppose that..." assumption, but there are counter-examples to $C^1$-version of Sard's theorem, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258141/a-counterexample-for-sards-theorem-in-c1-regularity

Comment: "Suppose that" comes from a Dubovitskii Theorem; as explained in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296312/do-you-know-important-theorems-that-remain-unknown/296314#296314 and in the article '[B. Bojarski, P. Hajłasz, P., P. Strzelecki, Sard's theorem for mappings in Hölder and Sobolev spaces. Manuscripta Math. 118 (2005), no. 3, 383–397.]'  Dubovitskii proved a more general result than Sard. Note that thesis of  Dubovitskii's theorem (my "Suppose that") and Sard's theorem are different.

Comment: I suggest you check carefully what Dubovitsky's Theorem says and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: >Theorem (Dubovitskii). Let $f:M^m→N^n$ be a mapping of class $C^k$. Set $s=m−n−k+1$. Then
$H^s(f^{−1}(y)∩Crit(f))=0 \; \; \text{for} \;  H^n \; \text{a.e.} \; y∈N^n $.

In my case $m=N+1$, $n=1$, $k=1$, $s=m-n+k-1=N+1-1+1-1=N$. Where am I wrong?